# Estilizar elemento a varios niveis a cima

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como posso alterar o background da div#whatever ao clicar em uma li, como no exemplo abaixo.(utilizando apenas css)

```html
<div class="whatever"></div>
 <section class="content">
        <article class="personagens">
            <h2>Lista de Pokémons</h2>
            <h2>Lista de Digimons</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Bulbasaur</li>
                <li>Ivysaur</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Tem que ser exatamente em css ?

Comment: @MauroAlexandre sim

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer isso apenas com HTML/CSS é necessário utilizar um hack com checkbox.

Se liga na adaptação que fiz para o seu código [nesse fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/felipecorreiams/wtLhLfqm/3/):

```css
#btnControl {
  display: none;
}
#btnControl:checked + .whatever {
  background: red;
}
.whatever {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btnControl" />
<div class="whatever"></div>

<section class="content">
  <article class="personagens">
    <h2>Lista de Pokémons</h2>
    <h2>Lista de Digimons</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label class="btn" for="btnControl">Bulbasaur</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="btn" for="btnControl">Ivysaur</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</section>
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

se vc quiser fazer puramente com css fica assim

```css
#a:hover + #b {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

isso é apenas um ex mas vc adapta para sua li

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Jasar, mas já tentei isto. O que preciso fazer é alterar a div.whatever a partir de um clique em uma li contida dentro de outros elementos, como na estrutura acima.

Comment: Pablo. Utilize o selector :active que ele irá simular o clique.

Comment: da forma que nosso amigo Felipe Correia postou funciona he uma aplicação do que eu t passei. tbm pode ser feito com um href pois o <a> tem a propriedade active depois de clicada,